# TIFF compression using LZW

Tags: c#, compression, tiff, lzw

Is there a class in C# library which does LZW compression on TIFF images. I know there is a compression scheme inviolving LZW being present, but using that doesnt decrease the file size whatsoever. Is there any thing that Im assuming wrong? Please correct me if I am.

Comment: So, what is the use of TIFF encoder and decoder classes provided, if we can directly get the bitmap and use LZW compression on them??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because LZW is loseless compression, you can compress TIFF images or any other kind of data using the same way. In C# you can use the [SharpLZW library](http://sharplzw.sourceforge.net/).

--EDIT (1)--

If you want to produce a TIFF file with embedded LZW compression respecting the TIFF specification look at section 13 of the [specification](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf).

--EDIT (2)--

There was a patent but it is now [expired](https://web.archive.org/web/20090626052026/http://www.unisys.com/about__unisys/lzw/).

Comment: Can you please elaborate, the need of TIFF encoder and decoder while compressing images, are they even required??

Comment: IANAL, but I am pretty sure that patent expired years ago.

Comment: yup im sure the patent expired